# rendering equations as images and including them in Word/PowerPoint output documents with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm gratuitously cross posting this [from the R Studio community page](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rendering-equations-as-images-for-microsoft-output/13862) as this is a bit esoteric.

Is there a way to ask Knitr to render my equations from R Markdown into images and then stick the resulting images into my final document? The use case I have in mind is overcoming some of the shortcomings of MSFT Equation editor when knitting to Word/PowerPoint. If the equation was simply an image, then I could have LaTeX quality equations in my MSFT docs, which would be fabulous!

The closest thing I have found is [using `latex2exp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) and putting in an R Code chunk that produces a figure which is actually a rendered LaTeX formula. I kinda like this sort of hack, but `latex2exp` has some limitations.

Comment: Possible alternative strategy: create an image an insert it in your Word/Powerpoint document with the [`officer`-package](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/).

Comment: I can't figure out how to script the creation of the equation image, however. Inserting images into MSFT docs is easy, that's handled by R Markdown just fine. No need for `officer` to do that bit.

Comment: Could you include some example rmd-code with an equation that needs to be converted to an image?

Comment: @jaap sure: $x$ ... I'd like to make that an image.

Comment: Render to html first using the webtex option and then docx?

Comment: The webtex option is a great find... I was not familiar with that. I wish I could use that switch directly with word output!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, webtex is an easy solution.  Pandoc's `--webtex` switch has no effect when targeting docx. However, a Lua filter can be used to the same effect.

```lua
local mediabag = require 'pandoc.mediabag'
local utils = require 'pandoc.utils'

local function url_encode(str)
  local encode_char = function(c)
    return ("%%%02X"):format(string.byte(c))
  end
  return str
    :gsub("\n", "\r\n")
    :gsub("([^%w%-%_%.%~])", encode_char)
end

local function webtex_url(formula)
  return 'https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?' .. url_encode(formula)
end

function Math(el)
  local filename = utils.sha1(el.text) .. '.png'
  local mime, contents = mediabag.fetch(webtex_url(el.text), '.')
  mediabag.insert(filename, mt, contents)
  local img = pandoc.Image({}, filename)
  return el.mathtype == 'DisplayMath'
    and {pandoc.LineBreak(), img, pandoc.LineBreak()}
    or img
end
```

Save this to a file and pass the file to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` option. It will convert all equations into png images via webtex.

Comment: I'd love to see that added to pandoc!

Comment: @tarleb where are the png files saved (if at all)?

Comment: @FaridCheragi those are kept in memory, but you can save them by passing `--extract-media` to pandoc.

Comment: @tarleb  you have misspelled my name so I was not notified of your comment. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @FaridCheraghi sorry about that, I was on mobile when I wrote that. Glad to hear that it works.

Comment: @tarleb , no problem. Out of curiosity, is it possible to generate these equation images with my local Latex binaries instead of `--webtex` switch, which is a bit slow? I am looking at [this Q/A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/34058#34058) but  would rather to do it through Pandoc.

Comment: Found [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/latex-formulae-pandoc)